# Need jQuery selector for <ul> inside a hovered <li>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my XHTML code:

```
<ul id="MenuBar1">
  <li>
    <div class="menuBox">Category 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="hasasubmenu">
    <div class="menuBox">Category 2</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="link.html">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="link.html">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="link.html">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hasasubmenu">
    <div class="menuBox">Category 3</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="menuBox">Category 4</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Actually, I want to make a menu with hover interaction to show sub links. (anyway, a standard menu:))

And here is my JS code:

```
/* menu handler */
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#MenuBar1 li.hasasubmenu').hover(function(){
    **(selector that select the sub <ul> of the hovered <li>)**.toggle();
  });
});
```

Can you help me finding the selector (in bold(**) in the JS code) which will be used for toggling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) or [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
/* menu handler */
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#MenuBar1 li.hasasubmenu').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').toggle(); // select the ul
      });
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/2GY4V/

Comment: thanks a lot! perfect :)

You made me discover jsfiddle! This will help me a lot!!
thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using jQuery for this? You could do this using CSS only
http://jsfiddle.net/XBdAL/

```
<ul>
   <li>List Item 1</li>
   <li>List Item 1
      <ul>
         <li>List Item 2</li>
         <li>List Item 2
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS

```
ul {
        list-style: none;
        width: 150px;
        }

li {
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        }

li:hover {
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        }

ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        left: 140px;
        top: 4px;
        }

li:hover ul ul {
        display: none;
        }

li:hover ul, li:hover li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        }
```

I should use the CSS only, because there are some users/brosers that don't support JS.

Comment: ... and there are some browsers that don't support `:hover` over anything else than `a` elements.